# Count of first time emails by month in MySQL

Tags: mysql

So we log when we send our clients promotional emails and sometimes clients are in our database for a while before they receive their first email so we want to know how many clients received their first ever email by month for the past 12 months.

So far I can only think to get the information month by month but there has to be a way to query all 12 months in a single query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `id`
FROM
    `table1`
WHERE
    `sendtime` BETWEEN '2019-08-01' AND '2019-09-01'
        AND `id` NOT IN (SELECT 
            `id`
        FROM
            `table1`
        WHERE
            `sendtime` < '2019-08-01');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the minimum `sendtime` for each user:

```
SELECT id 
FROM table1
GROUP BY id
HAVING MIN(sendtime) BETWEEN '2019-08-01' AND '2019-09-01'
```

If you want the number of these ids:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) counter
FROM (
    SELECT id 
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING MIN(sendtime) BETWEEN '2019-08-01' AND '2019-09-01' 
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select date_format(min_sendtime, '%Y-%m') yyyy_mm, count(*) no_clients
from ( 
    select id, min(sendtime) min_sendtime
    from table1
    group by id
) t
where min_sendtime >= date_format(current_date, '%Y-%m-01') - interval 1 year
group by yyyy_mm
order by yyyy_mm
```

This gives you one row for each of the last twelve months (that has a least one customer that received their first email), with the count of "new" email over the month.